# How do I uninstall the AMD Graphics Card drivers but not the CPU drivers?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card

I'm installing a new 750ti SC and I need to uninstall my current drivers (AMD video card) before installing the nVidia card into my computer. The problem is that I can only find guides to uninstalling ALL AMD drivers, including the chipset drivers.
How do I uninstall JUST the graphics drivers and not the drivers that are required for my system to work like my CPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for Device Manager page and where you can uninstall selective drivers of any devices connected?. If so, then Windows key + r > in the run box, type devmgmt.msc and press enter. This will show you Device Manager page. Now, expand the "Display Adaper" in the right pane and select and then right click the driver you wish to uninstall.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will this make my screen go black? What will happen? I've heard that it will fall back on default windows drivers.

Comment: By default, Windows default driver will be installed. Then you can install the desired video card driver on top of it just by running the video card driver executables.